# (Not sure if possible) Count how many times specified users are entried, and list them ascending

Tags: php, mysql

Heres what i want:
Lets say we have a table that looks like this:

```
Player    |ID
----------|------
Max       |  1
Jacob     |  2
Jacob     |  3
Jacob     |  4
Jacob     |  5
Jacob     |  6
Peter     |  7
Peter     |  8
Peter     |  9
Peter     |  10
Jørgen    |  11
Jørgen    |  12
Jørgen    |  13
osborne   |  14
Jimmy     |  15
```

What i want is script that would collect all the entries with the same name, count them and list the top 3 ascending, with a result like this (in like a html table):

```
Player | votes
Jacob  |   5
Peter  |   4
Jørgen |   3
```

I am not asking for a whole script, just how to count it like this.

I tried searching for it, but i couldn't be specific enough as i didn't know exactly what to search for.

Answer (score 4):

That's easy, just use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT Player, COUNT(*) AS votes
FROM PlayerTable
GROUP BY Player
ORDER BY votes DESC
LIMIT 3
```

([demo on SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/M32MvDMfv3))